# que significa int32 maps int o system.char maps char?

Tags: c#

Que significa cuando se dice system.int32 maps int. System.char maps char. y asi sucesivamente, he estado investigando pero no entiendo bien. Se les agradeceria bastante.

Comment: Estás intentando hacer un mapping con Entity Framework?

Answer (score 1):

```
System.Boolean
System.Byte
System.SByte
System.Char
System.Decimal
System.Double
System.Single
System.Int32
System.UInt32
System.Int64
System.UInt64
System.Object
System.Int16
System.UInt16
System.String
```

Son los nombres completos de las clases que representan los tipos de datos básicos del **CTS** (Common Type System) .NET Framework o .NET Core. Esto quiere decir que estos nombres pueden ser usados desde cualquier lenguaje de programación que corre sobre .NET (como VB o F#)

En cambio

```
bool
byte
sbyte
char
decimal
double
float
int
uint
long
ulong
object
short
ushort
string
```

Son los aliases en C# de los misos tipos de datos de arriba de manera que no se tenga que escrbir el nombre común del BCL ni tener la necesidad de importar el namespace `System`. Estos keywords son exclusivos de C#

Por ejemplo VB tiene sus propios alias y estos son:

```
Boolean
Byte
SByte
Char
Decimal
Double
Single
Integer
UInteger
Long
ULong
Object
Short
UShort
String
Date (System.DateTime) // Este alias no existe en C#
```

Más información en:

- [Built-in types table (C# Reference)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/built-in-types-table)
- [Data Type Summary (Visual Basic)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/data-types/)

Answer (score 0):

si analizamos la documentacion oficial

[int (C# Reference)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/int)

veras que refleja que el `int` tiene como `.NET type` al `Int32`

> int solo es un alias de Int32

[char (C# Reference)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/char)

lo mismo sucede con el `char`

Aqui te lo explica genial

[Understanding .NET Primitive Types](https://weblogs.asp.net/dixin/understanding-net-primitive-types)

Te lo analiza hasta nivel del `IL`, pero basicamente rescato lo siguiente:

> int32 is a CLR primitive, represented by System.Int32 struct
>
> In C#, int is just an alias for System.Int32, supported by the C# compiler

Comment: Lo último es incorrecto. `int`siempre es `System.Int32` No depende si el procesador es 32 o 64 bits

Comment: No tengo forma de refutar lo que mencionas, solo me guio por el articulo. Como estas validando que int no depende de la plataforma? esta bueno para conocer. Si puedo decir que es un alias y uno es un value type mientras que el otro es un reference type, pero hasta alli llego

Comment: Conozco que int = Int32 y long = Int64, pero por debajo al compilar en diferente plataforma entiendo se deben ver afectados

Comment: Es fácil de probar. Sólo imprime `int.MaxValue` y `Int32.MaxValue` en una máquina de 64 bits y verás que dan el mismo valor de un entero de 32 bits

Comment: o usa un dissasembler y verás que ambos utilizan la misma clase `System.Int32`

Comment: El artículo que mencionas nunca dice lo que indicas en este post. Te recomiendo leerlo más detenidamente. Es más al final menciona algunos errores que la gente piensa y uno de ellos es que depende de la plataforma

Comment: ahora que lo releo veo que lo menciona como que algunas personas le comentan, pero es verdad que no lo asegura, voy a quitar esa parte para que no cause confusion